# JSON response with Http AKKA and case classes

Tags: json, scala, case-class, akka-http

I would like to build a simple stub server with several routes using Http AKKA.
I have the following case class:

```
  case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

  object Person {
    implicit def cardJsonFormat: RootJsonFormat[Person] = jsonFormat2(Person.apply)
  }
```

How can I return this case class as a JSON response.

My route looks like:

```
  case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

  def route =
    get {
      path("person") {
        complete {

        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try something like this:

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.marshallers.sprayjson.SprayJsonSupport
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol

case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

case object Person extends SprayJsonSupport with DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val personFormat = jsonFormat2(Person.apply)
}

object PersonRoute {
  val route =
    get {
      path("person") {
        complete {
          Person("Pawel", 25)
        }
      }
    }
}
```

More details and examples can be found in the [docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.8/scala/http/common/json-support.html).

Comment: I tried that already. I get this error:Type Mismatch, expected: ToResponseMarshallable, actial: Person. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: It looks like `personFormat` is not in the scope of your route. Could you show a complete example of your code? You could place it on pastebin/gist/etc.

Comment: The complete example is same as shown here. In this example it tells that: SprayJsonSupport is not found.

Comment: Have you added a dependency to `"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-spray-json-experimental" % "2.4.8".`?

Comment: Just added it and it seems to be working great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following library [akka-http-json](https://github.com/hseeberger/akka-http-json) used with [json4s](https://github.com/json4s/json4s) useful. It helps me cut down on the number of `jsonFormatX` statements. Every `jsonFormatX` statement is needed for every data type that needs to be marshalled / unmarshalled.

Just mix in the following trait where the marshall / unmarshall needs to occur:

```
import de.heikoseeberger.akkahttpjson4s.Json4sSupport
import org.json4s.jackson

trait JsonCodec extends Json4sSupport {

  import org.json4s.DefaultFormats
  import org.json4s.ext.JodaTimeSerializers

  implicit val serialization = jackson.Serialization
  implicit val formats = DefaultFormats ++ JodaTimeSerializers.all
}
```